# How do you display a negative number in 68000 assembly?

Tags: assembly, 68000

I think I'm missing something here because this should be easy but I just can't figure out how to display a negative number. I just want my program to output -1 if there is overflow, but it keeps showing 65535 instead. I just don't really understand how negative numbers in general work in 68k. I tried like this:

```
MOVE.W   #-1,D1
MOVE     #3,D0
TRAP     #15
```

and like this:

```
MOVE.W   #1,D1
NEG      D1
MOVE     #3,D0
TRAP     #15
```

So I'm not sure if the problem is only in getting the negative number to display or with storing it or both. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: 68k uses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement and you're printing it out with a function that treats the value as unsigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, unless one is using a programming language with a built-in way of outputting signed numbers, the proper way to display signed values is to test whether they are negative, and then if so invert them and output a `-`.  Then use whatever means would be employed for unsigned numbers.  In some cases it may be necessary to process the `-` after processing everything else (e.g. if one is exploiting the ability of some LCD controllers to process data in right-to-left order, one might output numbers in lowest-digit-first order, stopping once one has a zero residual, then output a "-" if needed, and finally outputting enough blanks to pad the field) but such things may be accommodated by having the "output number" routine accept a parameter indicating what character, if any, should precede the number; the caller could then pass a "+", "-", or " " as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way are:

```
MOVE.L   #-1,D1 
MOVE     #3,D0 &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;Display signed number in D1.L in decimal in smallest field.
TRAP     #15
```

And:

```
MOVE.W   #1,D1
NEG.L    D1
MOVE     #3,D0 &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;Display signed number in D1.L in decimal in smallest field.
TRAP     #15
```